# Connected apps - how to find out which apps are actively used

Tags: connected-apps

I've been tasked with looking into and enabling the For admin-approved users, limit API access to only allowlisted connected apps.  The goal is to prevent users from installing connected apps.

What I don't understand is the relationship between Connected Apps, e.g. what shows up when you go to the "Manage Connected Apps" setup link, and the "Connected Apps OAuth Usage" link.

E.G. if I have a connected app appear in the Manage Connected Apps menu called "Hello World API", how do I know if that app is actually in use? If I click into the app and click the "View OAuth Usage" link, I don't see anything related to "Hello World API".